# Kubernetes : is it possible to broadcast message from one service to another service?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networking

I am working on a building a distributed system where I need to refresh a particular configuration to all the pods of two services, service-A and service-B. This configuration is handled by another service-C. A user can send an api request to service-C which needs to be propagated to all the pods of service-A and service-B.

1. Service A and Service B works on grpc and are not exposed to the world.
2. These services can be running on different nodes (so we cannot have a file system shared between these).
3. The configuration will be around 100KB on average and there will be around 100K such configurations.

Possible ideas:

1. I can create a message bus using kafka and push these configuration on that bus which is then listened by different pods. Problem with this approach is service A and service B will have 100s of pods running so there will be like 100s of consumer groups, also if a new pod comes up it has to consume the queue from the beginning which will be time consuming.
2. Using a light weight transient key value store like consul or etcd, so Service-C will push the data in consul which can then be read by Service-A and Service-B. The issue with this approach, so many pods listening to consul can cause latency.

Can someone please help me with some ideas how i can achieve this on kubernetes natively?

Thanks.

Comment: is this a  java spring application or something else?

Comment: Its a golang application.

Comment: one idea: service C talks directly to K8s API to update a configMap, services A and B are configured so their pods mount that configmap, which will get updated on their filesystems automatically. Services A and B would need to poll that file or get notified of changes, and reload the config. This is really just using etcd under the hood, that's how K8s works.

another idea: use Consul. Have the agent running as a daemon set, not inside each pod, that might reduce your latency concern; though consul should scale to a large number of agents regardless. https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-helm

Answer (score 0):

You could use configMap for this. From application C create or update a configMap by calling kubernetes API using kubernetes go client library and volumeMount the configMap in service A and service B.The service A and service B can have a mechanism to check if anything has changed in those configMaps and if yes then reload config in the memory. The mechanism in service B and service A could just be calculating a hash of the configMap and keep comparing that periodically with what is there in the Filesystem(via volumeMount of the configMap) and when there is a change reload the configMap in memory.

Comment: Thank. will config map be able to scale up to 100k of 100kb configs?
Also is there any other way to send data to all the pods ? kind of broadcast?

Comment: ConfigMaps are internally stored in the etcd which is pretty scalable..I can't really prove it but you should give it a try